# Hide user records from certain groups of users

Tags: sharing-rule, owd

I have a requirement in my org as below

I have a set of users who can access only limited set of data(say 3 objects data).
In their profile I have removed cred permisions to other objects except 3 required objects there by preventing them to access entire data in the org.

But the issue is these users are able to access the others user records searching their name on the global search.

I looked for the option to disable CRED for User object like I did for Account and other objects but I dont see any any option like that on the profile level.

I tried setting OWD private for User object but this idea impacts entire org.

Please Suggest

Comment: Is the global search searching user record or any other records like Accounts?

Answer (score 0):

Setting OWD to Private is the cleanest way to do it. You can then open up access to other users using sharing rules. This way these records wont appear in global search,reports,API-based pulls and list views.